# Run a program from Qt

Tags: qt, terminal, qprocess

I am working with Qt in Linux. I need to run the "evince" pdf reader from Qt.

I have been searching and as I understand I can use Qprocess to make it work. Something like this:

```
QStringList args;
    args.append("/home/user/presentacion0.pdf");
    QProcess p(this);
    p.start("/usr/bin/evince", args, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    p.waitForFinished();
    QString p_stdout = p.readAllStandardOutput();
    QString p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();
```

But I always get the following error:

*No protocol specified
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:*

So I tried the `system(char *cmd)` from `stdlib.h` and does not work
system("/usr/bin/evince /home/user/presentacion0.pdf");

I think system() does not work because "evince" is a graphical application. However I can run "ls", "mkdir", etc. commands with `system()` without problems.

Please I need help with this topic.

I Really appreciate your help in advance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're running your Qt app from an application (most likely shell) that doesn't have `DISPLAY` environment variable set properly (it's usually `:0`). QProcess uses environment of the calling process.

If you're not really interested in grabbing `evince`'s stdout and stderr, and you don't need to wait for its finish, then I would go with `QProcess::startDetached()`.